# WebView in Cocoa not rendering

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my window controller, I have this:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"webView = %@", webView);
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:
         [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
             [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]]];
}
```

My understanding is that should make the webView in my window now download and render Apple's home page. But all I see in a white panel. What am I missing?

(I've checked that webView is not null; NSLog shows something like 
"webView = <WebView: 0x10be7c3b0>")

I've also tried the more modern approach, but still had no success:

```
[webView setMainFrameURL:@"http://www.apple.com/"];
```

Comment: why do you use this way `[webView mainFrame]` instead of the simple `webView` property?

Comment: @holex, I don't understand. Can you show me what you mean with a line of code? I got what I'm doing from a doc at developer.apple.com

Comment: I'm always using it: `[viewWeb loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_url]];` where the `viewWeb` is an instance of `UIWebView` and the `_url` is an instance of `NSURL`. I've never have any problem with it. what is `[webView mainFrame]` you put in your code?

Comment: UIWebView is for iOS, right? My code is for an OS X application.

Comment: oh, yep... **you are right**. it is my mistake. :( I though it is an iOS issue.

Comment: It should work, and does work for me - anything else special you're doing? Make sure your app has a network connection if it's sandboxed.

Comment: @Vervious Ah...sandboxing...I think that's it. I'll check in the office tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this project is sandboxed, the solution in this case was to add the relevant entitlement to the project.